# how to create a new file in an immutable directory

Tags: linux

I have changed the directory attribute immutable by `chattr +i /testdir`; but I need to create files in that directory.

Or is there any way that nobody can delete the directory but the owner can still write in that directory?

Answer (score 3):

The way to get what you need is:

`chattr +a /testdir`

Set the permissions on the directory itself so that only the owner has write permissions.

The `a` switch makes it so that the files can be created and modified inside but not deleted.

The `man`page for `chattr` only says what `a` does for files but it does indeed do the above when used on a directory as I found out myself when searching for a way to do the same.

Comment: Folder will be append-only, meaning that once you create a file in it, you can never delete it. Only solutions around this are (a) either to remove the `a` attribute before deleting files, or (b) use Romeo's solution and make a 2-level directory tree, with the first directory's permissions set to `r-xr-xr-x`. It's a pity that there's no "un-removable directory" flag that prevents a folder from being removed, while permitting to alter/remove its content.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
chattr -i /testdir
```

will remove this flag. Then you create the new file and again

```
chattr +i /testdir
```

you should set only `r` and `x` of parent directory for group and other to prevent removing the directory

Answer (score 0):

The immutable attribute set on a directory only affects this directory and its immediate (e.g., 1st level) content. Not the content of a sub-directory.

So, if you only need to add files to this directory, without ever having to modify or to delete files from it; then using the `a` attribute like Nasir Riley showed is the way to go.

On the other hand, if you want to be able to have a full control of the directory, while preventing the directory from being renamed/deleted, then you could use a subfolder, and make only the upper-level folder immutable, for example :

```
$ mkdir d1
$ mkdir d1/d2
$ sudo chattr +i d1
```

You can then verify that you have full control over `d1/d2` :

```
$ touch d1/d2/f1
$ mv d1/d2/f1 d1/d2/f2
$ rm d1/d2/f2
```

While at the same time the `d1` folder is immutable :

```
$ sudo rm -rf d1/
rm: cannot remove 'd1/d2': Operation not permitted

$ sudo mv d1 d3
mv: cannot move 'd1' to 'd3': Operation not permitted
```