# Prevent deletion of folder by accidentally moving or deleting parent folder that has no immutable attribute

Tags: delete, xattr

In the PARENT_FOLDER I store subfolders with some works I am producing each week, e.g. right now I have these contents:

```
~/PARENT_FOLDER/StuffProducedTwoWeeksAgo/...
~/PARENT_FOLDER/StuffProducedLastWeek/...
```

Each week I add a new folder with the work I have done (video editing, whatever) which I want to keep at hand and readable inside `~/PARENT_FOLDER/` but I don't want it accidentally erased, so after I copy a new folder inside `~/PARENT_FOLDER/`, I will do

```
chattr +i -R StuffProducedThisWeek
```

I *don't want* to

```
chattr +i ~/PARENT_FOLDER
```

because I still want to copy, create or delete new stuff inside it freely. But I want certain things (those folders called `Stuff*`) inside there to be secure against deletion.

After setting the `+i` attribute to `~/PARENT_FOLDER/StuffProducedThisWeek` it seems I cannot delete or modify it from inside `~/PARENT_FOLDER/`, and in the file browser its icon appears with a small lock.

But then I can go up one level and simply move to the trash `~/PARENT_FOLDER` with an accidental hit to the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key that goes unnoticed and the next day I can empty the trash and my work is lost forever.

So, I want to be able to modify the contents of `~/PARENT_FOLDER/` except those subfolders marked with the `+i` attribute but, if I accidetally try to move or delete `~/PARENT_FOLDER/`, I would like the OS to prevent me from doing that in order to protect the immutable subfolders.

How is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create a new file in an immutable directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447788/how-to-create-a-new-file-in-an-immutable-directory) Just use the append-only `+a` attribute instead of the immutable `+i` on `~/PARENT_FOLDER`.